# Include Role to access token

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, maui

My current status: A user authorises himself in a .net Maui app via MSAL. The access token received is sent as a bearer header to the asp.net API.

`if (_client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization==null) _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + App.Token);`

The API requires a role as authorisation.

`group.MapGet("/", [RequiredScope(RequiredScopesConfigurationKey = "AzureAd:Scopes")][Authorize(Roles = "AD")] async Task<Results<Ok<List<Clients>>, NotFound>> (string ZIP Code) =>`

The Maui App is registered in Azure AD "mobile device and desktop application".
As a result, the returned access token does not contain then configured role. The role is only included in the ID token. Configuring the token via Optional Claims does not change the access token in any way.

I can read the role from the ID token in the .net Maui app, but how do I get the role into the access token before sending it to the API? Or is there a way to extend the header to include the role?

Comment: Please read the [Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) section to know how to properly ask a question and [Do not force tags into titles}(https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) of your questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the API registered separately in Azure AD?
Roles are returned for the application the token is meant for.
In this case if the API app registration does not have the roles then they won't be in the token.

In that case you need to either:

1. Make one app registration for both the MAUI app and API app (and acquire access token for itself)
2. Or you will need to add the same roles to the API app registration and set them to the user on both app registrations

Comment: Thank you for your reply and happy new year. 
Yes, the API is registered separately in Azure AD. Both registrations have the same role and user assigned. But isn't it right that at this point no contact is made to the register of the API? 
At least only the ID of the Maui APP is sent to the Microsoft server as "app ID." I receive an access token without role and an identity token with role.  Since I am only able to send the access token to the API, it does not find the needed role.

Comment: What scopes are you using when acquiring the access token?

Comment: Oh, here is the connection. That seems to be the right question. Since I am using the MSAL library, I used the given User.Read Scope and created a scope with the same name for my API app. But it seems to be, that it still uses the MS Graph API register and not my API register. If i create a scope name which only exits in my API register, I get an error, that the scope does not exist. Ok, I'll try to figure that out. Thanks for the hint..

Comment: That's the issue then :) "User.Read" is actually not a full scope id. It is a short id that only works with MS Graph API. The full scope id is app-client-id/Scope.Name or app-id-uri/Scope.Name. So for the MS Graph API scope the full scope id would be `https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read`. The app registration Expose an API tab should actually provide you the full scope ids.

Comment: Just changing the line in the MSAL lib which returns the scopes for MSGraph 
 return this.MSGraphHelper.MSGraphApiConfig.ScopesArray;
to code that returns my custom API-Scope solved the problem. Thanks a lot!